# How to create an expression that separates Ids in SSIS using the Derived Column function?

Tags: ssis

How to separate the column so that it has two new columns called CountryCode and CustomerID? For example, it is currently combined as CountryCodeCustomerId "0005+34"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the left side:

`LEFT(CountryCodeCustomerId,FINDSTRING(CountryCodeCustomerId,"+",1) - 1)`

Use the left function.  To find the length, use FINDSTRING and subtract 1.

For the right side:

`RIGHT(CountryCodeCustomerId,FINDSTRING(REVERSE(CountryCodeCustomerId),"+",1) - 1)`

Use the right function.  To find the length, do the same as above, except first REVERSE the string, i.e. `43+5000`